# Output Top Level Item No. of BOM

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have written SQL Code to completely explode all bill of materials :

This is the table data :

```
CREATE TABLE bomline(
   itemno VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,compno VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL 
  ,quantity NUMERIC(9,6) NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY(itemno,compno)
);
INSERT INTO bomline(itemno,compno,quantity) VALUES ('1000','1100',2.000000);
INSERT INTO bomline(itemno,compno,quantity) VALUES ('1100','1200',3.000000);
INSERT INTO bomline(itemno,compno,quantity) VALUES ('2000','2100',4.000000);
INSERT INTO bomline(itemno,compno,quantity) VALUES ('2100','2200',2.000000);
```

Here's my SQL Code :

```
WITH tmpbom([itemno], [compno], [quantity], [level]) 
     AS (SELECT S1.[itemno], 
                S1.[compno], 
                CAST(S1.[quantity] AS NUMERIC), 
                1 
         FROM   bomline AS S1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT S2.[itemno], 
                S2.[compno], 
                CAST(S2.[quantity] * TS.[quantity] AS NUMERIC), 
                TS.[level] + 1 
         FROM   bomline AS S2 
                INNER JOIN tmpbom AS TS 
                        ON S2.[itemno] = TS.[compno]) 
SELECT [itemno], 
       [compno], 
       Isnull(quantity, 0) AS [quantity] 
FROM   tmpbom
```

This is what I get at the moment :

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| ItemNo | CompNo  | Quantity  |
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1000   | 1100    |  2.000000 |
| 1100   | 1200    |  3.000000 |
| 2000   | 2100    |  4.000000 |
| 2100   | 2200    |  2.000000 |
| 2100   | 2200    |  8.000000 |
| 1100   | 1200    |  6.000000 |    
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

I want to have this result where all child components are related to their top level ItemNos with accumulated quantity:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| ItemNo | CompNo  | Quantity  |
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1000   | 1100    |  2.000000 |
| 1000   | 1200    |  6.000000 |
| 2000   | 2100    |  4.000000 |
| 2000   | 2200    |  8.000000 |    
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, some sample data as DML and desired results.

Comment: please check here on how to ask:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I do feel... question is not clear.

Comment: Show us the current result, and the expected result!

Comment: even after your edit, the question is not very clear. please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: I deleted unnecessary data.

Comment: usually, 5 - 6 rows of data is enough to understand the problem. You posted about 30 rows. that's way too much.

Comment: what is the rule that will dictate what is a TopLevel , ParentLevel ? illustrate with sample data. leave nothing to imagination.

Comment: I completely simplified the example.

Answer (score 0):

First, values that item no not in compno

```
    SELECT
        BL.itemno,
        BL.compno,
        BL.quantity
    FROM
        dbo.bomline BL LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.bomline CBL ON BL.itemno = CBL.compno
    WHERE
        CBL.itemno IS NULL
```

Output of first query:

```
    itemno compno quantity
    ------ ------ ---------
    1000   1100   2.000000
    2000   2100   4.000000
```

Second query:

```
    SELECT
        BL.itemno,
        PBL.compno,
        BL.quantity * PBL.quantity AS quantity
    FROM
        dbo.bomline BL INNER JOIN 
        dbo.bomline PBL ON BL.compno = PBL.itemno
```

Output of second query:

```
    itemno compno quantity
    ------ ------ ---------------
    1000   1200   6.000000
    2000   2200   8.000000
```

Result:

```
    SELECT
        BL.itemno,
        BL.compno,
        BL.quantity
    FROM
        dbo.bomline BL LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.bomline CBL ON BL.itemno = CBL.compno
    WHERE
        CBL.itemno IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        BL.itemno,
        PBL.compno,
        BL.quantity * PBL.quantity AS quantity
    FROM
        dbo.bomline BL INNER JOIN 
        dbo.bomline PBL ON BL.compno = PBL.itemno
```

Result output:

```
    itemno compno quantity
    ------ ------ --------------
    1000   1100   2.000000
    1000   1200   6.000000
    2000   2100   4.000000
    2000   2200   8.000000
```